# Get boost::asio::io_context from a boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket to exec a custom function

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm porting my [cli](https://github.com/daniele77/cli) library to  `boost` v. 1.70

It uses  `boost::asio` to implement a simple tcp server.

Somewhere in my code, I have a  `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` object and I need to exec a custom function in the same  `io_context`.

Until version 1.69 the following code was fine:

```
boost::asio::io_context& ioc = socket.get_io_service();
ioc.post( [](){ /* my custom code */ } );
```

With version 1.70, however:

- `socket` does not expose the method `get_io_service` anymore
- `io_context::post` is deprecated

I tried:

```
boost::asio::execution_context& ioc = socket.get_executor().context();
boost::asio::post(ioc, [](){ /* my custom code */ } );
```

but does not compile.

Can you please help me to port the code to version 1.70?

Comment: Try this: `boost::asio::post( socket.get_executor() ,[](){});`. [live](https://godbolt.org/z/vbdtZo)

Comment: It does compile. But has executor value semantics? If I copy an executor into another one, they both run the code into the same thread?

Comment: There is no problem to copy executor, see [this reference page](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/Executor1.html). You can have multiple executors all of them will share the same io_context instance. Yes, they do. If you have only one thread which started `io_context::run`, your posted lambda will be executed inside the one thread, it doesn't matter that you post handlers by copy of executor.

Comment: Thanks @rafix07 . If you write an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Answered  a pretty similar question just now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56225374/alternative-to-missing-method-in-last-version-of-boost-asio-library (you might be co-workers :))

Comment: @sehe Now, I can put answer with the link to your one  :D

Comment: Or if the OP agrees, he/we can close this question as a duplicate

Comment: @sehe as you can see, I asked my question *before* the one you answered. So, technically, we should close as a duplicate the other question, not mine :-)

Comment: @DanielePallastrelli I don't think that's relevant. A question duplicates another or it doesn't. It doesn't matter whether a monkey typed it upside down in another universe. It's your choice. If you think it answers the question, link it.