# Alternative to missing method in last version of Boost asio library

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Some years ago, I wrote a email client using Boost asio library.

There are a abstract class **ICON** with four subclasses.

**POP3conN**    to flat POP3 communications

**POP3conS**    to secure POP3 communications

**SMTPconN**    to flat SMTP communications

**SMTPconS**    to secure SMTP communications

**ICON** has a member

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_
```

and two virtual procedures, defined in each subclass:

```
void SMTPconN::run() { socket_.get_io_service().run(); }
void SMTPconN::reset() { socket_.get_io_service().reset(); }
```

The application worked fine with boost_1_63_0. But when I try update to boost_1_70_0, the compiler (MS V Studio 2015) complains in both definitions:

```
class "boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>" has no member "get_io_service".
```

Because I want do the minimal change in what is a huge amount of code and complex logic: do is there some workaround to this missed method?

Answer (score 9):

The docs state under [Networking TS compatibility](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/net_ts.html) that you can use `get_context().context()`, which will get you a `io_context` instance (which replaced `io_service` somewhere around boost 1.64/1.65 IIRC).

> #### Networking TS compatibility
>
> Boost.Asio now provides the interfaces and functionality specified by the "C++ Extensions for Networking" Technical Specification. In addition to access via the usual Boost.Asio header files, this functionality may be accessed through special headers that correspond to the header files defined in the TS. These are listed in the table below:
>
> [...]
>
> Use get_executor().context() to obtain the associated io_context.

Both `get_io_service()` and `get_io_context()` were previously in place to facilitate porting, but they have in the mean time also been deprecated and obsoleted.

PS: Also see [Get boost::asio::io_context from a boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket to exec a custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56223084/get-boostasioio-context-from-a-boostasioiptcpsocket-to-exec-a-custom) which is eerily similar to your question but specifies a specific use-case.

The comments there have the ***decidedly better solution*** for that use-case:

```
socket.get_io_service().post([](){ /* my custom code */ } );
```

Becomes

```
post(socket.executor(), [](){ /* my custom code */ } );
```

Answer (score 2):

The subclasses: **POP3conN** and **SMTPconN** have a member:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_
```

Similarly, **POP3conS** and **SMTPconS** have a member:

```
boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>  socket_;
```

The first argument of all constructors is a pointer to `io_service`. Some like:

```
IPCON::IPCON(boost::asio::io_service* ioserv_, ...) { ... }

POP3conN::POP3conN(boost::asio::io_service* ioserv_, ....) {...}
```

**First change**: in the abstract class **IPCON** has been added a new member:

```
boost::asio::io_context* iocontPtr_;
```

wich is initialized in the constructor replacing the old reference to `io_service`:

```
IPCON::IPCON(boost::asio::io_context* iocont_, ...) { ... }
```

In the constructors of the subclasses has been added initialization to such member:

```
POP3conN::POP3conN(boost::asio::io_context* iocont, ....) : IPCON(iocont) { ... }
```

**Second change**: all occurences of

```
boost::asio::io_service
```

Can be replaced by

```
boost::asio::io_context
```

The problematic expressions

```
void SMTPconN::run() { socket_.get_io_service().run(); }
void SMTPconN::reset() { socket_.get_io_service().reset(); }
```

appears now like this:

```
void SMTPconN::run() { iocontPtr->run(); }
void SMTPconN::reset() { iocontPtr->reset(); }
```

It seems that the functionality of the old `io_service` has been replaced by the new `io_context`.