# boost 1.72 get icmp::socket io_service for icmp::resolver

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I updated my project from boost 1.67 to boost 1.72. Now I can't compile it because of the following:
I had code:

```
boost::asio::ip::icmp::resolver resolver(m_socket.get_io_service());
```

where `m_socket` is object of `boost::asio::ip::icmp::socket`. Compilation error in this case looks like:

> Error C2039   'get_io_service': is not a member of 'boost::asio::basic_raw_socket'

Similar error was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56225374/alternative-to-missing-method-in-last-version-of-boost-asio-library) and the proposed solution was to call `get_executor()` method and then get executor's context. So I changed my code. Now it looks like:

```
boost::asio::ip::icmp::resolver resolver(m_socket.get_executor().context());
```

But still get compilation error:

> Error  C2039   'get_executor': is not a member of 'boost::asio::execution_context' (compiling source file PathMTUDiscovery.cpp)    SocketsLib  C:\Work\BuildFiles\boost\1.72.0\include\boost\asio\detail\io_object_impl.hpp    87

I tried to find something in [Networking TS compatibility](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/net_ts.html), but didn't find the solution here.
Anyone knows how to solve the error properly?

Comment: Ctor of resolver takes executor type, not context, so try: `boost::asio::ip::icmp::resolver resolver(m_socket.get_executor());`.

Comment: @rafix07, it works, thanks. I tried it yesterday because error text says that it should be executor, however IntelliSense underline it with red and I even didn't try to compile.

Comment: Intellisense strikes again